# Is it possible to use a repository in the AuditorAwareImpl class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement a reference in the database who and when an entity was created/updated.
The createdAt and updatedAt date are already working.

But I can see when I set a breakpoint that the return of the getCurrentAuditor method gets called about ten times till a response comes to the client. And the response is an error with the *CONFLICT* HttpStatus-Code.

I have a class named *BaseEntity* where the attributes are defined.

See my classes below:

```
class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Person> {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Override
    public Optional<Person> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of(personRepo.findByUserPrincipalName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() + "@email.com"));
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Person> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person updatedBy;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        if (this.createdAt == null) createdAt = new Date();
        if (this.updatedAt == null) updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

}
```

#### Edit v1 from Zorglube(does not work for me)

```
class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Person> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public Optional<Person> getCurrentAuditor() {
        PersonRepository personRepo = context.getBean(PersonRepository.class);
        return Optional.of(personRepo.findByUserPrincipalName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() + "@email.com"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Person> {

    @Override
    public Optional<Person> getCurrentAuditor() {
        PersonRepository personRepo = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(PersonRepository.class)
        return Optional.of(personRepo.findByUserPrincipalName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() + "@email.com"));
    }
}


@Component(value = "applicationContextProvider")
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static class AplicationContextHolder {
        private static final InnerContextResource CONTEXT_PROV = new InnerContextResource();
    }

    private static final class InnerContextResource {

        private ApplicationContext context;

        private void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
        AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.setContext(ac);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do I get the ApplicationContextProvider from?